# ACS_BLOCK and ACS_CKBOARD not working in nCurses, while rest of ACS chars are working

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, curses, widechar

Some wide characters like `ACS_ULCORNER` and others are working fine, where as `ACS_BLOCK` and `ACS_CKBOARD` are not working as expected, instead they are shown as `#`.

[image: Code Used for the program] and

[image]

Compiled using this command.

`gcc test2.c -lncurses -o test2`

I highlighted both with White arrows for easy identification.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: Actually all that's needed is the value of `TERM` (and possibly which system is used, and what version of ncurses).

Answer (score 1):

What's [***missing***](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) is this:

```
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

If your locale supports UTF-8, then ncurses will check a built-in table of Unicode values to augment the terminal description's **`acsc`** string.

Here's xterm displaying equivalent information using the ncurses test-program:

[image: ncurses with alternate character-set in uxterm]

while the terminal description omits some of those, as shown by my modified version of [altchars](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:altchars):

```
Unknown line drawing character label(s) found in acsc capability:
|
Unassigned characters from the alternate character set:
h   board of squares
+   arrow pointing right
,   arrow pointing left
-   arrow pointing up
.   arrow pointing down
I   lantern symbol (old)
0   solid square block
Start alternate character set sequence: ^[(0
End alternate character set sequence: ^[(B
```

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` along with using linking `ncursesw` worked fine. But in perl, problem is there. Will have to figure out how to do this in perl.

Comment: (barring "perl6"...) perl doesn't actually use those ncurses features (I'd expect only the characters defined in terminfo to work).  But when you have something specific, a perl script demonstrating the problem would help.